# Azure AD B2C redirect_uri error says The redirect URI com.bol.azure_test://oauth/redirect provided in the request is not registered for the client id

Tags: flutter, azure-ad-b2c

I am working on a cross platform mobile app in Flutter which will be protected using Azure_AD_B2C. I am just wondering why is it so hard to have the redirect_uri match the one in Azure app with the mobile client. Here is how I got the redirect_uri setup in the Azure portal -
[image]

And here is how I have it setup in my Flutter app -

```
onPressed: () async {
     print("Find Azure API Button Click");
     var queryParameters = {
         'p': "B2C_1_signupsignin",
         'client_id': "client_id",
          'nonce': 'defaultNonce',
          'redirect_uri': 'com.bol.azure_test',
           'scope': "offline_access openid",
                'response_type': "code",
                 'prompt': "login",
                  'grant_type': "authorization_code"
             };
         var uri = Uri.https(
               '{tenant}',
                '/{tenant/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
                 queryParameters);
          var response = await http.get(uri);
                 print('Response -' + response.body);
           },
```

With the above code I am trying to open the signupsignin policy in a browser for authentication and return back to the app once authentication is done. Currently it is not opening the browser and the policy.

If print response.statuscode I get 200. But If I print response.body then I get the error saying the below.
The redirect URI com.bol.azure_test; provided in the request is not registered for the client id {client_id;."};

I have been stuck on this for a few weeks now.

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

Do a network trace and see what redirect URI you are sending, and compare that to what you have configured.

Make sure you are using the right clientID.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error ***"The redirect URI XXX provided in the request is not registered for the client id"*** usually occurs if there is a mismatch in configuring the redirect URI in the Azure Portal and in the Flutter app.

To resolve the error, try including the **`redirect_uri`** in the Flutter app like below:

```dart
'client_id': "client_id",
'nonce': 'defaultNonce',
'redirect_uri': 'msauth://com.bol.azure_test',
```

And in the Portal as:

[image]

Make sure the **`ClientID`** you are passing is valid:

[image]

I agree with *rbrayb*, if still the issue persists try running a network trace and compare the `redirect_uri` you are passing.

I tried to authorize by using the below endpoint:

```json
https://testaadb2c.b2clogin.com/testaadb2c.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
&client_id=Client_ID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=redirect_uri
&response_mode=query
&scope=offline_access openid
&state=12345
```

When I passed the valid URIs, **I am able to generate the code value successfully like below**:

[image]

***If still the issue persists***, Check the below:

- Check whether you have Registered the Application the Azure AD B2C Tenant.
- You can install Fiddler, enable HTTPS capture and the `redirect_uri` value and compare it in the Portal.
- Try setting the **`redirect_uri`** as `com.bol.azure_test` both in Azure Portal and in the Flutter App and try.

**Reference:**

[Flutter_azure_b2c: A flutter library to handle the Azure B2C authentication protocol](https://github.com/nodriver-ai/flutter_azure_b2c) by Luca Calacci

Comment: Thanks Rukmini for the detailed explanation. I tried the endpoint https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignUp_SignIn/oauth2/v2.0/authorize&client_id=ClientId&response_type=code&redirect_uri=msauth://com.bol.azure_test&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access openid&state=12345. I got a 404 error saying the resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed or temporarily unavailable. Also I checked on the clientId & the redirect_uri, they all match according to what I have setup on my flutter app.

Comment: I also checked my Run User flow endpoint on this tool https://redirectdetective.com/  to see the redirects, it says no redirects found. There is something totally wrong with my configuration.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I have been getting the same error with my B2C tenant. I am using the following endpoint: `https://<tenantName>.b2clogin.com/<tenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=<userFlowName>&client_id=<clientId>&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms%2F&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login` to get an auth token and I am getting the same error: "invalid_request: The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The URI is definitely registered in the app registration.